# How to Create new dataframe from existing dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this [Main DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5ijD.png).
How Can I extract new data frame from it like:
[Second DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dOHk.png)

I know  `df['Group'].value_counts().index`  shows me counts of each 'Group' but I don't know how to create new dataframe with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a new dataframe by using for example `groupby` like this to do this counting:

```
df.groupby("Group", as_index=False).size()
```

Other interesting options for groupby that you might want to use depending on use case are `dropna=False` and `sort=False`.

And to rename the size column to counts you use can use rename: `.rename(columns={'size': 'Count'})`